# Mapping .Net Core Entities with One to Many relationship to Angular 2 interfaces

Tags: c#, json, angular, typescript, .net-core

I'm creating a simple Blog using .Net Core C# and Angular 2.

Retrieving all the Posts worked fine, but I have now added an Array of Comments to each post and this has caused the following error:

[image]

Does TypeScript need more information about the comments?

**Angular component:**

[image]

**API Method:**[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem.

Due to the circular reference inside of Entity Framework the JSON failed to parse.

I manged to fix it by adding this option inside the startup.cs:

```
 services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```